# Cant solve System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#

I want view *PerformanceCounter name* and create console app for view it. But have one error. Help to solve problem

```js
Console.WriteLine(Environment.MachineName);
PerformanceCounterCategory[] categories;
PerformanceCounter[] pfs;

categories = PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories();

foreach (PerformanceCounterCategory category in categories) {
    //Console.WriteLine("-> {0} - {1}", category.CategoryName, category.CategoryType);
    try {
        pfs = category.GetCounters();

        foreach (PerformanceCounter pc in pfs) {
            //Console.WriteLine("\t->{0}", pc.CounterName);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        try {
            InstanceDataCollectionCollection idcc = category.ReadCategory();
            foreach (InstanceDataCollection v in idcc.Values) {
                //Console.WriteLine("\t->{0}", v.CounterName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exx) {
            Console.WriteLine(exx.Message);
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("\n**********************************************\n");
```

> An unhandled exception of type "System.ArgumentException" in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> For more information: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary:
>   "sent requests per second" key is added: 'sent requests per second'

Comment: Successfully run your code, no exception. In which line you get it?

Comment: I use try/catch. Exception message was at Console.WriteLine(exx.Message);

Comment: I got multiple exceptions on the first catch block, none on the second... what are you trying to do exactly?